# background-cover is broken in Android Chrome, in this web page (only?)

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome, background-image

While I have css rules with `background-cover` that work well in Chrome for Android, somehow the very same rules fail in this particular website

The weird thing is that if I paste the same `background-image: url(backgrounds/landing-two.jpg);` rule on the Dev Tools, it doesn't work, but if I uncheck it (leaving the original one) then I can see the original rule working

The site is https://kuworking-theme-landing-two.netlify.com/

What can be happening?

```css
    background-blend-mode: var(--theme-ui-colors-backgroundimg__mode,unset);
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    background-size: cover;
    display: grid;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(backgrounds/landing-two.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in 0s;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

[image: animated gif of the behavior]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has esoterically been solved by removing a `transition: all 0.5s ease;` rule (this is set in a `styled-components` context)